# Negative Determinant and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

How can I proof that a Matrix with a negative determinant hat at least a real eigenvalue ?

Comment: Are you in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :** Trigonalize in $\mathbb{C}$. If all the eigenvalues are non-real, then for each eigenvalue $\omega$, you also have $\overline{\omega}$ as an eigenvalue. What can you say of the determinant in that case ?

Comment: The determinant will then be positive, which is impossible. Thank you